# Receive Messages from Chrome Extension in a C++ program

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a Chrome extension which starts an executable C++ file using `NativeHostMessaging` through the json file which points to this file.

This .exe file tries to read the messages send from extension. First, it reads 4 bytes which depicts the length, then it reads the number of bytes equal to length. The very first thing that this file does is wait for a message from the extension.

However, the executable file did not receive anything from extension and keeps on waiting. Nothing exists on the `STDIN(0)`.

Is this a security issue or I am doing something wrong? Did I have the read/write sequence in the wrong order?

Comment: Is the Question not clear?

Comment: I just edited your question to make the question easier to understand. If it does not deliver your intended question, please let me know and feel free to change it.

Comment: Why the Question was down voted?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how mine looks like for windows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "json\json.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    //save in a file so we know it was called
    FILE *fh_debug; int errorcode;
    errorcode =fopen_s(&fh_debug, "debug.txt","ab+");
    std::string msg = "Host Called";
    fwrite( msg.c_str(), sizeof(char),msg.size(),fh_debug);

    unsigned int uiSize = 0;
    std::string inputStr;

    //read the first four bytes (=> Length)
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int read_char = getchar();
        uiSize += read_char * (int) pow(2.0, i * 8);
    }

    //for debug "0000" = 808464432
    if ( uiSize == 808464432 ) {
        uiSize = 0; inputStr = "{\"text\":\"tester\"}"; 
    }

    //debug record size
    msg = std::to_string(uiSize);
    fwrite( msg.c_str(), sizeof(char),msg.size(),fh_debug);

    //read the text
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uiSize; i++)
    {
        inputStr += getchar();
    }

    //debug record json message
    msg = inputStr;
    fwrite( msg.c_str(), sizeof(char),msg.size(),fh_debug);

    //get the text
    std::string theText;
    Json::Value jsonRoot;
    Json::Reader jsonReader;
    bool OK = jsonReader.parse(inputStr, jsonRoot);

    try {
        theText = jsonRoot.get("text", "no text element").asString();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
        throw e;
    }

    //debug record json message
    msg = theText;
    fwrite( msg.c_str(), sizeof(char),msg.size(),fh_debug);

    std::string strOut = "{\"text\":\"Hello " + theText + "\"}";
    uiSize = strOut.length();

    msg = strOut;
    fwrite( msg.c_str(), sizeof(char),msg.size(),fh_debug);

    std::cout << char(((uiSize>>0) & 0xFF));
    std::cout << char(((uiSize>>8) & 0xFF));
    std::cout << char(((uiSize>>16) & 0xFF));
    std::cout << char(((uiSize>>24) & 0xFF));
    std::cout << strOut.c_str();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me on OSx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(){

    char cBuffer[65536] = {0};
    FILE *fh;
    fh=fopen("/Users/mycode.text","ab+");
    std::string msg="\"This is a Test\"}";
    std::string hello="itsme";
    int ii=4;
    while(ii)
    {
        unsigned int uiSize = 0;
        std::string strOut = "{\"type\":";
        strOut=strOut + msg;

        uiSize = strOut.length();

        std::cout << char(((uiSize>>0) & 0xFF));
        std::cout << char(((uiSize>>8) & 0xFF));
        std::cout << char(((uiSize>>16) & 0xFF));
        std::cout << char(((uiSize>>24) & 0xFF));
        std::cout << strOut.c_str();

        std::cin.read((char*)&uiSize, sizeof(unsigned int));
        if(uiSize > 0 && uiSize < 65536)
        {
            memset(cBuffer, 0, 65536);
            std::cin.read(cBuffer, uiSize);
            fwrite(cBuffer,sizeof(char),uiSize,fh);
            std::string strIn(cBuffer);
            msg=strIn+"}";
            if(!strIn.compare(hello))
                exit(0);
            ii--;

        }
        else
            break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```